# Give priority to secondary ORDER BY field in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sorting, sql-order-by

I have been struggling with a MySQL query and it seems I cannot find any solution to the problem.

I have a database of documents which I want to order by time. Very simple. The complication is the following: if two or more documents share the same value in a column called `correlation_id`, I want them to be placed next to each other. If I simply order by `correlation_id` first, the correlated rows will be placed at the top or bottom. I want them to be placed at the location of the most recent document.

As an example, suppose I have a list of documents, and documents `B` and `D` are "correlated" with an id, just a number they have in common in a column.

When I use `ORDER BY time`, the output is:

```
time          document          correlation_id
1h            A                 0
2h            B                 1
4h            C                 0
4h            D                 1
6h            E                 0
```

When I use `ORDER BY correlation_id, time`, the table becomes primarily ordered by correlation and will give:

```
time          document          correlation_id
2h            B                 1
4h            D                 1
1h            A                 0
4h            C                 0
6h            E                 0
```

I do not want the correlated items to be placed on top or below, but at the position of the most recent document, so it would look like:

```
time          document          correlation_id
1h            A                 0
2h            B                 1
4h            D                 1
4h            C                 0
6h            E                 0
```

As a query it would have to look like:

`SELECT * FROM DOCUMENTS ORDER BY [if (correlation_id<>0) {order by correlation_id first}], time DESC`

Thank you in advance.

Comment: how about `ORDER BY time, correlation_id DESC`?

Comment: No since it would be sorted by `time` anyway. In the extremely rare case where the `time` is the same in multiple rows, it will order this small selection by their `correlation_id`. As you can see this is not exactly what I am looking for ...

Comment: Can you provide the dataset? Which will help in writing query.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just wrote what I would want the query to look like underneath my post!

Comment: so you need a 4th column that gets the min time for the related correlation_ids and order by it first while displaying time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Demo at Rextester](http://rextester.com/LLN67615) for both answers below.

I'm **not** a proponent of using selects in selects...  The join to get the minimum time and the grouping seem like they would be more difficult to maintain; and added to confusion.  So select in select may be easier to understand and maintain though it should be slower in the long run.

We use a select to get the min time for each non-0 correlation_ID; for those that are zero we just use the records time. and coalesce these two values giving us a MinTime column that we can then order first by and then by time to get the desired ordering.

```
SELECT BaseSet.*, coalesce((SELECT min(time) MT
             FROM DOCUMENTS MinCorT
             WHERE MinCorT.Correlation_ID = BaseSet.Correlation_ID
               and correlation_ID <> 0), time) MINTIME
FROM documents BaseSet
ORDER BY MINTIME, Time
```

The other approach which I believe is faster (more so the more rows you have...) but more difficult to understand/maintain.

```
SELECT BaseSet.*, coalesce(MinCorT.MinTime, BasetSet.Time) MinTime
FROM documents BaseSet
LEFT JOIN (SELECT min(Time) MinTime, Correlation_ID
            FROM Documents MinCorT
            WHERE Correlation_ID <> 0 
            GROUP BY Correlation_Id) B
  on BaseSet.Correlation_ID = MinCorT.Correlation_ID
ORDER BY MinTime, time
```

The 2nd query assumes you have an index on correlation_ID, time  The reason the 2nd query would be faster is because it only has to do the join once.  Whereas the first query has to execute a subquery for each record in documents. Thus you can see the more documents you have the slower the query should be.

The second query generates a subset of data (MinCorT) containing the min time for each correlation_ID.  We LEFT join the base set to this set so we have the min time for each document having a correlation_ID. We use coalesce to use the base document time in the situations where the the correlation_ID is 0 (no mintime record).  We again end up with a a MinTime column which we can order by and a time column to produce the desired ordering.

The second approach is more code and thus more difficult to maintain but should operate with greater performance in the long run.

Given your sample data; both queries result in:

```
+------+----------+----------------+---------+
| Time | document | Correlation_ID | MinTime |
+------+----------+----------------+---------+
| 1h   | A        |              0 | 1h      |
| 2h   | B        |              1 | 2h      |
| 4h   | D        |              1 | 2h      |
| 4h   | C        |              0 | 4h      |
| 6h   | E        |              0 | 6h      |
+------+----------+----------------+---------+
```

Though in the second we could move the coalesce down to the order by and not have the MinTime column at all.  However for understanding I thought I would display it.

Comment: Sorry about that I generally do name the aliases better; but in my haste I went back to my shorthand.